# Why can't I access a variable for data binding?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have this function below inside `AppComponent` class in Angular which makes an AJAX call and receives a JSON file and stores it in a variable on a button click.

```
getData = function() {
    let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', 'https://mywebsite.com/data.json');
    request.onload = function() {
      let data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
    };
    request.send();
  }
```

I can't access the `data` from HTML with a use like this:

```
<p>{{data.name}}</p>
```

It only works if I use it inside here

```
request.onload = function() {
    let data = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
    document.getElementById('myParagraph').innerHTML = data.name;
};
```

How do I make the `data` variable accessible outside this function and use it for binding in HTML?

Comment: are you using angular 2 or angularjs

Comment: `let data` is scoped only to the `onload` function. It's a local variable. No, it's not accessible anywhere else.

Comment: you answered yourself, you store the value in a variable, not an instance member

Comment: It's the latest version @SachilaRanawaka

Comment: How to make it available for global scope? @deceze

Comment: https://angular.io/tutorial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you must have a variable at class level like this

```
export class SampleClass implements OnInit {

data: any ;

constructor() {
}

 getData() {
  let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open('GET', 'https://mywebsite.com/data.json');
  request.onload = this.manageData.bind(this);
  request.send();
 }

 resolveData(ev){
    this.data = JSON.parse(ev.target.response);
    console.log(this.data);
 }
}
```